# Build vlan header in c

Tags: c, network-programming, ethernet

I need to build a vlan header.
I have code that build eh header  (struct ether_header) and it work ok.

```
/* Ethernet header */
memcpy(eh->ether_shost,src_mac_.data(), 6);
memcpy(eh->ether_dhost,socketAddress.sll_addr , 6);

/* Ethertype field */
eh->ether_type = htons(ETH_P_IP);
```

I didnt find struct for vlan_eth_header , so i create my own and populate it like this:

```
struct vlan_ethhdr {
  u_int8_t  ether_dhost[ETH_ALEN];  /* destination eth addr */
  u_int8_t  ether_shost[ETH_ALEN];  /* source ether addr    */
  u_int16_t          h_vlan_proto;
  u_int16_t          h_vlan_TCI;
  u_int16_t ether_type;
 };

    /* Ethernet header */
    memcpy(eh->ether_shost,src_mac_.data(), 6);
    memcpy(eh->ether_dhost,socketAddress.sll_addr , 6);
        eh->h_vlan_proto = htons(0x8100);
        eh->h_vlan_TCI = htons(VLAN_ID);
    /* Ethertype field */
    eh->ether_type = htons(ETH_P_IP);
```

It seems that i did it wrong.
It seems that Wireshak even didnt recognize the packet (the old code sent tcp packet and send them correct).
Any advice?

Comment: Print out the hex (or copy it from wireshark) up to and including where the IP header should be, it should make it easy to see where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code to construct VLAN is correct. It dosnt worked for me at the first place , because i forgot to change the size of the packet to be bigger now.
Pay attention that TCI is not only VID its included priority and CFI. In my case they both zero , so i dont need to use mask and padding for TCI.

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.wireshark.org/VLAN

- DstMAC [6 bytes]
- SrcMAC [6 bytes]
- Type [2 bytes]
- - 0x8100
- VLANTag [4 bytes]
- - Priority [0..2 bit]
- - - 0
- - CFI [3 bit]
- - - 0
- - ID [4..15 bit]
- - Ethernet Type [16..31]
- - - 0x0800 (IP)

My guess is you're not setting the VLAN_ID correctly.

At first you should avoid any structure padding issues by just creating some test packets in a byte[] buffer that way you can be sure you have everything correct. Then you can debug your structure and htons byte ordering with confidence because you know what the correct values should be.

Comment: Do you have any guess how should i set the vlan id?

Comment: i saw this reference http://osdir.com/ml/linux.network.bridge.ebtables.devel/2006-07/msg00000.html , but dont know if its correct . I will try with bytes as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your structure is properly packed? The compiler adds some padding by default. It can be easily disabled.

For example, with GCC:

```
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(0)
struct vlan_ethhdr {
  u_int8_t  ether_dhost[ETH_ALEN];  /* destination eth addr */
  u_int8_t  ether_shost[ETH_ALEN];  /* source ether addr    */
  u_int16_t          h_vlan_proto;
  u_int16_t          h_vlan_TCI;
  u_int16_t ether_type;
 };
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Comment: I based it on struct eth_header from linux . Now i see that there is difference that they have there }__attribute__ ((__packed__)); I didnt copy it. can it be the reason?

Comment: You can see that in the following link , its defiend without pack http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/if_vlan.h#L52    with or without packed its the same sizeof (18 - additional 4 bytes)

Comment: @user1495181 You can do a sizeof() on your structure if in doubt its exact size.

Answer (score 0):

802.1Q 4-byte VLAN tag is generally considered as in the form of `0x8100+pri+cfi+vlan`.
The wireshark way of depicting vlan tag as `pri+cfi+vlan+etype` (excluding 8100, but including etype of the data payload) is somewhat unique.
However, the overall packet format and length is correct either way.